# Declare a dictionary without Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I do have a main Excel VBA Programm which calls a Sub Routine with late binding because using the Tools->References-> Microsoft Scripting Runtime is not feasable for the know reasons.

```
Main Program    
Dim Dict As Object
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Call SubRoutine(Dict)
```

next step is to send the dictionary to my SubRoutine

```
Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
do something
end
```

will result in compiling error which is expected because I do not have the reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
The Questions is now, how to solve that problem to declare the dictionary.
By using

```
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Would empty the dictionary.

Comment: Use `Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Object)`

Comment: ;-) Have tried this but it changes the Type. With the Reference the Locals Window show the dictionary as Type Dictionary/Dictionary.   With as Object it is Object/Dictionary. This doesn't help me I need the dictionary.

Comment: In my testing it works fine.  What do you mean by _it changes the Type_?

Comment: If I'm using the Microsoft Scripting Runtime with tools->references to compile and run the code you can see with view->Locals Window that the Type of dict is Dictionary/Dictionary. But this I can't use. So changing to     SubRoutine(Dict As Object) changes the Type

Comment: `Object/Dictionary` is exactly what it should be with Late Binding.  This means the variable is an `Object`, which can reference _any_ object type. `/Dictionary` means it's currently referencing a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively asking how to use late binding instead of early binding ([one article discussing this](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm), [more articles](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vba%20early%20late%20binding)).

Instead of the following, which implies early binding (i.e. setting an explicit reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library):

```
Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
```

you need to declare your Sub's parameter as a generic `Object` type, as is required when using late binding (i.e. no explicit reference set, letting the program figure things out at runtime):

```
Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Object)
```

Think of `Object` as a container that can hold any kind of object — but once you put an object in it, e.g. a `Dictionary`, then that's what it becomes. In the Locals window it will appear as `Object/Dictionary`, meaning the container is `Object` (which is largely irrelevant to you, don't worry about this) but the nature/behaviour is `Dictionary` (which is what you want).

**Addendum:** This last sentence isn't quite as true as I thought it was. See explanation in follow-up question: [Runtime Error with Dictionary when using late binding but not early binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26585884/119775)

Comment: Sound feasable for me but later on in the code I run in further problems.   What I do is putting the dictionary into an array with     `Arr(c) = Dict.Keys(c)`. The Array is defined as Variant which should also work. The compiler now says Runtime Error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get Procedure did not return an object. It works great with `Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Scripting.Dictionary)` but not with `Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Object)`

Comment: That's a new question — please post it as such. Also please consider accepting this answer if it helps with your original question. [How does accepting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)