# Runtime Error with Dictionary when using late binding but not early binding

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

What I do is putting a dictionary into an array within a Sub Routine

That is the definition

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
ReDim Arr(0 To Dict.Count - 1)
For c= 0 To Dict.Count - 1 
   Arr(c) = Dict.Keys(c) ' <~~~~~~ Error here
Next c
```

The compiler says

> Runtime Error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get Procedure did not return an object.

It works great with

```
Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
```

but not with

```
Public Sub SubRoutine(Dict As Object) –
```

Please refer to [Declare a dictionary without Microsoft Scripting Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582591/declare-a-dictionary-without-microsoft-scripting-runtime)

Comment: how did you declare the `Arr` and what is `c` in this context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### `<Solution>`

You do this

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
ReDim Arr(0 To Dict.Count - 1)
For c = 0 To Dict.Count - 1
    Arr(c) = Dict.Keys(c)
Next c
```

But looping like this is quite unnecessary. That's what `Arr = Dict.Keys` does. So instead of the above, just do

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Dict.Keys
```

The added bonus is that *this makes the error go away*.

#### `</Solution>`

---

But why did the error occur in the late bound version of the code but not the early bound?

#### `<Educated guess>`

With early binding, the compiler knows that [the `.Keys` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265334%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) takes no parameters — it just returns an array. So it interprets `Dict.Keys(c)` as `{returned array}(c)` and returns the `c`th element of that returned array.

With *late* binding, I guess the Object container doesn't know that the `.Keys` method doesn't take parameters (a.k.a. arguments), so it sends `c` to it as a parameter. But there is no such getter (or setter) defined, hence the error. To remedy, you can [apparently force it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26587499/119775) to send no parameters to the `Keys` method by saying `Dict.Keys()(c)`, which brings back the `{returned array}(c)` behaviour.

#### `</Educated guess>`

This is the first time I bump into a case like this where the late bound code behaves differently than the early bound.

Comment: Bizarre behavior! OP could also resolve by: `Dict.Keys()(c)` but as you note, it shouldn't be necessary to iterate the keys to construct the array, since the `Keys` method *returns an array*.  +1!

Comment: Doesn't work for me - either with early or late binding. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
ReDim Arr(0 To Dict.Count - 1)
For c = 0 To Dict.Count - 1
   Arr(c) = Dict.Keys()(c)
Next c
```